# Which arcane spells at each level deal damage over several rounds?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I'm looking for spells that deal damage over several rounds for my sorcerer. Melf's Acid Arrow  is an example of a second level wizard spell that does hit point damage over several rounds. Maw of Chaos is a ninth level spell.

My sorcerer has reached sixth level and I am looking for a third level spell for now, and higher level spells for later.

I prefer ranged touch attacks over melee attacks, and over spells that allow saving throws or spell resistance. Arcane spells that do hit point damage, ability damage, conditional effects like Dazed and Staggered, etc. are all good answers.

Comment: While I'm usually a big proponent of list questions, this strikes even me as too broad. I understand (*completely!*) the desire for a comprehensive list, but if you could add to the question the situation surrounding your need, this might help folks narrow down a list to those that would be best for you.

Comment: Yeah, that’s going to be **hundreds** of spells.

Comment: I like Melf's Acid Arrow, and my Sorcerer just reached sixth level. I am looking for a third level spell for now, and higher level spells for later on.

Comment: I did not realize that there are hundreds of spells, as I am not finding them at the moment. If you know that many, then narrow your list down to those with a duration of 1 round/level. I like ranged touch attacks over melee attacks and over spells that allow spell resistance or saving throws. I guess I have tried to weed those out subconsciously.

G

Comment: Add those caveats to the question and I think that could be something we can help with.

Comment: You may also wish to consider a maximum spell level for consideration. Do you think your game will continue far enough for 7th, 8th, and 9th level spells to matter?

Answer (score 2):

So *Melf’s acid arrow* is the only spell that does all four of the following:

- Damage over time
- Saving throw: None
- SR: No
- Ranged touch attack

#### Damage over time with no saving throw or SR, but no ranged touch attack

If we eliminate the requirement of a ranged touch attack, there are some options:

- *Acid fog* (Sorcerer 6th, *Player’s Handbook*)—a tiny amount of acid damage on top of *solid fog*. *Solid fog* is a disgustingly powerful spell, so this is good, but the addition of minor damage isn’t really worth being two spell levels higher.
- *Acid rain* (Sorcerer 5th, *Heroes of Battle*)—a small amount of damage (though much better than *acid fog*), plus it makes the ground slick or muddy, halving movement speed. I would still prefer *solid fog*.
- *Bleakness* (Sorcerer 4th, *Player’s Handbook II*)—Darkness, minor damage against living creatures, minor healing and turn resistance for the undead.
- *Caltrops* (Sorcerer 0th, *Spell Compendium*)—identical to dropping a bag of caltrops, but without having to actually have caltrops. Actually not bad for a cantrip.
- *Caustic mire* (Sorcerer 4th, *Complete Mage*)—creates difficult terrain that does small acid damage as creatures move through it. Also increases the damage of fire effects used on targets in the area (small bonus though).

None of these stay with the target, however, they merely damage those who stay inside. They do all limit movement to make it harder to get out, but it’s generally not impossible. *Acid fog* is definitely the best of these, but only because it is *solid fog* and *solid fog* is better than any of these (including *acid fog* itself, if we count *acid fog*’s level against it, which we should).

#### Damage over time ranged touch attack with no saving throw, but SR: Yes

Eliminating SR: No as a requirement doesn’t seem to actually get us anywhere; there are no SR: Yes spells that deal damage over time, have no saving throw, and involve a ranged touch attack, at least as far as I can find.

#### Damage over time ranged touch attack with SR: No, but a saving throw

Likewise, I cannot find any spells in this category.

#### Damage over time ranged touch attack with both SR and saving throws

Ranged touch attacks that deal damage over time, but allow saving throws and spell resistance: only one.

- *Blackfire* (Sorcerer 8th, *Complete Arcane* or *Spell Compendium*)—deals some Constitution damage per round, which is good, and can spread to other targets, which is pretty cool... but the Constitution damage isn’t all that high, and this is an **8th-level spell**. Waiting 5 rounds to kill even a low-Constitution target isn’t even remotely acceptable at that level.

#### Damage over time melee attacks

If we switch to a melee touch attack instead of a ranged touch attack, we get slightly more options, including one of the most notorious spells in the game, *shivering touch*. Note the existence of the [Reach Spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#reachSpell) metamagic feat, which turns touch attacks into rays (but also increases their spell level by 2, which is quite a hefty cost), as well as the [archmage’s arcane reach high arcana](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/archmage.htm#arcaneReach), which does much the same but at the generally-lower cost of a single 7th-level spell slot per day.

- *Emerald flame fist* (Sorcerer 7th, *Complete Arcane* or *Spell Compendium*)—a touch deals fire damage and, if your target fails a Fortitude save (and does not resist, since spell is SR: Yes), take fire damage each round until the spell ends (each round gets another Fort save to halve that particular round’s damage). Unfortunately, the damage isn’t great, **particularly** for a 7th-level spell (honestly, it would be mediocre on a **3rd** level spell).
- *Lesser shivering touch* and *shivering touch* (Sorcerer 1st and 3rd, *Frostburn*)—the general consensus is that these spells have been misprinted; at the very least they’re missing some information. They deal 1d6 Dexterity damage and 3d6 Dexterity damage, respectively, with no save (though they are SR: Yes). You will notice that those damage values are quite high at this level—many suspect they were intended to be *temporary Dexterity penalties* rather than damage, because they *also* have a duration of 1 round/level. Damage doesn’t usually get a duration; damage spells are usually instantaneous. But... it does *say* damage. And a duration. Rules-as-written,  that *could* imply that it isn’t 1d6 Dexterity damage or 3d6 Dexterity damage, but 1d6 or 3d6 Dexterity damage *per round*. Suffice to say that a 1st-level spell shouldn’t be no-save paralyzing, uh, just about everything ever after a few rounds, but that’s kinda what the spell seems to say. (The other interpretation is that the spell works like *chill touch*, allowing you to use the Dexterity-damaging touch attack repeatedly. Really no matter what it’s supposed to do, the description should spell it out better.)

  Note that these spells are notoriously good, and often among the most highly-recommended spells in the game, **even when you rule them to be instantaneous.** They are particularly good at, and famous for, killing dragons, for instance: *most* dragons are *usually* paralyzed by a single *shivering touch*. (In my campaigns, dragons almost-always learn *prismatic scales* specifically to counter *shivering touch*.)
- *Spirit worm* (Sorcerer 1st, *Magic of Faerûn*)—with a touch, deal either 1 Constitution damage per round or (if the target saves) 1d2 hp damage per round. SR: Yes, but still, not bad for a 1st-level spell.

---

And that’s it; I am not going to try to go through all the SR: Yes, saving-throw-allowing, non-touch-attack spells that deal damage over time. There are simply too many of those to attempt to fit them all into a Stack Exchange answer, and like the non-touch-attack spells that *don’t* allow SR or a saving throw, most of them are going to be a form of damaging zone, not the same kind of “sticky” damage over time.

#### An Aside

With all that said, can I please warn you *against* doing what you’re asking for here?

Sorcerers get very, very few spells known. It is not good for them to have multiple spells that all do (more-or-less) the same thing. And damaging blast spells, themselves, tend to be very inefficient. Many sorcerers don’t actually bother even getting even *one* blast—a “dedicated blaster” would still probably just focus around one, particularly-good, spell, probably swapping it out later for a higher-level version. Maybe at the highest levels they might want two, *possibly* three, but even that’s pushing it and only when you have most of your spells.

And *Melf’s acid arrow* isn’t a bad choice for dedicating your blasting around, being SR: No and Saving throw: None, so you could totally focus on that and be a decent blaster (there are better options, though, including *orb of force* from *Spell Compendium*, or *orb of fire* from the same combined with Searing Heat from *Sandstorm*—plus there’s always *enervation* for the far more dangerous negative level blasting).

But even if you are specifically a blaster sorcerer, you want your other spells known to be allowing you to do all sorts of other things. The Sor/Wiz spell list is phenomenal, and one of the greatest advantages that sorcerers can have is the ability to have answers to so many different problems. Choosing a lot of redundant spells is a good way to miss out on a lot of potential.

Finally, on the subject of damage-over-time itself—it’s usually not a great idea. 3.5e combats are very, very fast—most are decided in the first 2-3 rounds, if not in literally the first round, and so delayed damage is usually not particularly helpful. Just a thing to be aware of. *Melf’s acid arrow* remains a fairly decent choice for blasting, but more because of its reliability than because of its extra delayed damage.